# Why is my input text not being found by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a Pomodoro (http://pomodorotechnique.com/) style timer and I am trying to figure out why my code isn't working. I am trying to get text from the input but my code keeps going back to my default settings.

my javascript

```
function task() {
  taskReminderText = document.getElementById("form.taskReminder").value;
  timeInput = document.getElementById("form.timerLenght").value;
}
```

my html

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="checkForm()">
Task Reminder: <input id="taskReminder" type="text" name="taskReminder"><br>
Timer Length is <input id="timerLength" placeholder="20" type="text" name="timerLength"> minutes.<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="task()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to provide the `id` value when using **[document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)**:

```
function task() {
    taskReminderText = document.getElementById("taskReminder").value;
    timeInput = document.getElementById("timerLenght").value;
}
```